# Toggle icon color and change attribute?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

I am using fontawsome icons like this

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x" data-permisssion="access" data-permission-value="true"></i>  
<i class="fa fa-area-chart fa-2x" data-permisssion="file" data-permission-value="false"></i>  
<i class="fa fa-cc-mastercard fa-2x" data-permisssion="loop" data-permission-value="true"></i>
```

What i need on page load to all icons that have **data-permission-value = false** to have color red, and other to have color green, but when user toggle on that icon to chanege value to true and to change color to green. When user again click on icon to revert that value to false and change color to red?

Here is working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1714/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use your own classes inside the font awesome icons.
so just create those two css classes:

```
.redIcon{
    color: red;

}
.greenIcon{
    color:green;
}
```

created a click function to demonstrate the value change of data-permission. since you don't want to change all font awesome icons, add another class, like toggableIcon to those, that should be toggable...

```
$(".toggableIcon").click(function(){
   if($(this).attr("data-permission-value")=="true")
{
    $(this)
        .attr("data-permission-value", "false")
        .removeClass("greenIcon")
        .addClass("redIcon"); 
}else{
    $(this)
        .attr("data-permission-value", "true")
        .removeClass("redIcon")
        .addClass("greenIcon"); 
}

});
```

for initial setting of the color classes, to:

```
$(".toggableIcon").each(function(){
 if($(this).attr("data-permission-value")=="true")
 {
      $(this).addClass("greenIcon"); 
 }else{
     $(this).addClass("redIcon"); 
 }
});
```

see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1725/

Comment: I know this but this is not full answer on my question, plese read about adding value true and false

Comment: added a click function on the icon, to show you how to toggle color and values... i also changed your html, to have the new classes already initially loaded. but you could also do this via js on document.ready

Comment: another update, to use the click function only on those icons, that you want it to...

Comment: But this does not change data-permission-value

Comment: Sorry my mistake, but i dont want to add manualyy, i want ot check value and than add class, this way i have to add manualy?

Comment: you are right, it doesn't - changed it from .attr() to .data - now it doesn't work ... fix is on the way...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64616/discussion-between-errand-and-gorostas).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".fa").each(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('data-permission-value')) {
   var permisssion = $(this).data("permission-value");
   if(permisssion) {
    $(this).addClass("enable");
   } else {
    $(this).addClass("disable");
   }
  }
 })
 $(".fa").click(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('data-permission-value')) {
   var permisssion = $(this).data("permission-value");
   if(permisssion) {
    $(this).data("permission-value", false);
    $(this).addClass("disable");
    $(this).removeClass("enable");
   } else {
    $(this).data("permission-value", true);
    $(this).removeClass("disable");
    $(this).addClass("enable");
   }
  }
 });
});
```

and css

```
i.disable {
  color:red
}
i.enable {
  color:green
}
```

Comment: This will react on all I i dont want that i only need I that have data ttribute permission-value

Comment: As i said i dont want all .fa class :((

Comment: add condition for data attribute exist or not

Comment: This does not work on first click, i have to do twice click to make it work :(